# how to test that the wpf gui thread is Alive

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a modal wpf application and I need a way to monitor if the application is still working and the gui is responding using other process I cannot think of any idea how it can be done.

on other applications I just raise an "alive" event from my main loop but i don't have any clear main loop in the wpf app.

is adding a dispatcher timer to the application that will raise the event is a good idea?

Comment: What about `Process.Responding`?

Comment: does this cover all the options? may it be that the process is responding but that the UI thread is stuck/dead?

Comment: `Process.Responding` checks whether application is responsive to user(UI). this may return false when other threads are still working but UI becomes unresponsive(hung)! I don't know how this will behave when main thread exited

Comment: post as answer so i can reward you =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am converting my comment into answer on request.

I think you're looking for `Process.Responding` property. This will return whether UI is responsive or not.

Note: `Process.Responding` cannot be used with process which doesn't have UI.

> If a process has a user interface, the Responding property contacts the user interface to determine whether the process is responding to user input. If the interface does not respond immediately, the Responding property returns false. Use this property to determine whether the interface of the associated process has stopped responding.

If the process does not have a MainWindowHandle, this property returns true.

For more info  take a look at [Process.Responding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding.aspx)

Comment: Hello actually this does not mean ui is responsive. It can be still very lag even if it returns true always

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG What do you mean by *very lag*? Say in seconds or milliseconds.

Comment: it means that for example you update ui with 500 ms but some times it gets updated in 5 seconds

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Yes, but not more than 5 seconds. If more than 5 seconds, `Process.Responding` will return false. That is the microsoft's definition of whether a process is responding or not.